# JAVA - define a method in interface

Tags: java, class, methods, interface

I would like to define a method in JAVA interface. The reason is that every time I implement interface the method is the same, but I need to implement two interfaces for particular classes. Example:

```
interface A
method A()

interface B
method B()

class first implements A,B

class second implements A
```

method A() has same body everywhere.

Comment: You can do that in Java 8 with the `default` keyword. You can't do it in earlier versions. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

Comment: Or you can use `abstract` class in instead of `interface A`

Comment: As long as it's only interface `A` that needs implementations, you can get away in java <8 by making it an abstract class and keeping `B` an interface

Comment: I was thinking about abstract classes but there will be more interfaces with defined methods that I would like to implement. Thanks for an answer khelwood, your comment was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Java 8, you can put method implementations into interfaces.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

```
interface A {
    default void aMethod() {
        // method body
    }
}
```

In earlier versions, you would have to make `A` a class instead of an interface. An abstract class if that suits your model better.

```
abstract class A {
     public void aMethod() {
          // method body
     }
}

class first extends A implements B {
    ...
}
```